# Extract absolute depth to bedrock from SoilGrids WCS

Tags: soilgrids

I am wondering if it is possible to extract predicted absolute depth to bedrock values from SoilGrids WCS? I cannot find this variable in the web interface of the latest soil grid, only in the 2017 version.

Answer (score 1):

Soil depth is currently unavailable for V2 of soilgrids, but according to the [FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#Which_soil_properties_will_be_available_in_the_future) it is something that will be available in future.